# working with setTimeout function that dispatch an action from redux and resolve a promise chain with fetch call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

as the title says, I am stuck with some interesting issue with promises.
So i have a file that export object with a method, this function gets 2 values and return a setTimeout. the function gets a redux action (function dispatch) and a value for setTimeout.
The problem is when I want to make a fetch call and then when the promise fulfilled dispatch the action. the most close I got it this code:

```
const products = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3009/products');
    const data = await response.json();
    return data
}

const TIMEOUT = 100

export default {
    getProducts: (cb, timeout) => setTimeout(() => {
        new Promise(resolve => resolve(products)).then((data)=> cb(data))
    }, timeout || TIMEOUT),
}
```

Thanks to all who try to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK my code is actually works! I had a problem with the server.

Answer (score 0):

Your `default export` is difficult to read and probably buggy. Try declaring a const and exporting that.

Also, your `Promise` logic makes no-or-little sense: once `timeout` millis have passed, create a `Promise` automatically resolved into a pointer to the function `products`, and then call `cb` with that function as an argument.

```js
const products = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3009/products');
    const data = await response.json();
    return data
}

// Helper function to promisify setTimeout
const delay = (millis) => new Promise( resolve => setTimeout(resolve, millis));

// Use default argument value
const TIMEOUT = 100;
const getProducts = async (cb, timeout=TIMEOUT) => {
  await delay(timeout);
  const data = await products();
  cb(data);
}

export default getProducts
```

Comment: it actually doesn't work, the cb is not called. thanks for the help

Comment: Is there any error in the console or network tabs?

Comment: No as I said that was a server error. the code is fine